# html tag transfer it up or down use jquery and ajax when click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="line1"> <a>down</a> </div>
<div id="line2"> <a>up</a> <a>down</a> </div>
<div id="line3"> <a>up</a> <a>down</a> </div>
<div id="line4"> <a>up</a> <a>down</a> </div>
<div id="line5"> <a>up</a> </div>
```

When I click on the up or down links, I want the divs to interchange respectively.

I'm not looking for drag and drop functionality.

Comment: (Sarcasm) Sure, let me just take 15 minutes to program something for you...

Comment: What do you mean div are interchange?

Comment: yes, actually i use it menu management.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add classes to your up/down links:

```
<div id="menu">
    <div id="line1"> A <a class='up'>up</a> <a class='down'>down</a></div>
    <div id="line2"> B <a class='up'>up</a> <a class='down'>down</a></div>
    <div id="line3"> C <a class='up'>up</a> <a class='down'>down</a></div>
    <div id="line4"> D <a class='up'>up</a> <a class='down'>down</a></div>
    <div id="line5"> E <a class='up'>up</a> <a class='down'>down</a></div>
</div>
```

Add CSS to hide unused first and last link:

```
#menu > div:first-child a:first-child,
#menu > div:last-child  a:last-child { display: none; }
```

jQuery:

```
$('#menu').on('click', 'a', function() {
    var divs = $('#menu > div');
    var p = $(this).parent();
    var pos = p.index();

    if($(this).hasClass('up')) {
        p.insertBefore(divs.eq(--pos));
    }
    else if($(this).hasClass('down')) {
        p.insertAfter(divs.eq(++pos));
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/P4Xaf/

Comment: Downvote for just giving someone code, especially someone who didn't even bother to do any initial research.

Comment: +1 for giving an answer, thanks for helping people out.

Comment: @siride Your votes are your own business, of course, but that's not necessarily what they're meant for. Voting based on the quality and content of the answer itself, not on the context surrounding its posting, is always preferrable

Comment: @Clive: I think the answer itself is bad. Just dumping code is not really answering a question in a way that adds value to the site. It's solving someone's very specific problem in a way that doesn't lend itself easily to learning. I disagree with these types of answers on principle.

Comment: @siride Then we agree :) I concentrated too much on the second part of your comment, my bad

Comment: @Clive: well, I could have worded my comment better. See also my comments in the meta question linked by Samuel.